# NLP / Generator | StopIteration Error in Pattern.text.en library at function conjugate

Tags: design-patterns, nlp, iterator, generator

I'm trying to transfer a verb into its past form with the command

```
conjugate(oldWord, tense=this_tense, person=person, number=number)
```

I'm doing this operation on 500 sentences and the first one always raise this error.
so what I did was to call this function again with the same parameters for the first sentence, and it worked.
for the purpose of cleaner code for production I would like to solve this problem for the first sentence.
any suggestions?

Error description:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\zikit1\pattern\text\__init__.py", line 609, in _read
    raise StopIteration
StopIteration

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\zikit1\main.py", line 130, in <module>
    tmp = change_tense.change_tense(short_res[i], 'past')
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\zikit1\change_tense.py", line 124, in change_tense
    x1 = conjugate(oldWord, tense=this_tense, person=person, number=number)
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\zikit1\pattern\text\__init__.py", line 2208, in conjugate
    b = self.lemma(verb, parse=kwargs.get("parse", True))
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\zikit1\pattern\text\__init__.py", line 2172, in lemma
    self.load()
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\zikit1\pattern\text\__init__.py", line 2127, in load
    for v in _read(self._path):
RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration
```

I was expecting to get the verb in its past form.